# How to extract Key-Value pair from Excel and convert into JSON using Python and/or with Online converter format

Tags: json, excel, python-3.x, converters, keyvaluepair

i have below dataset which need to convert to JSON format with no header.

Is there a python code to extract in below format or an online converter or should I change my csv file format

Input:

```
 Afghanistan       AF
 Aland Islands     AX
 Albania           AL
 Algeria           DZ
 American Samoa    AS
 Andorra           AD
 Angola            AO
```

Output:

```
   {
       "Country": [
           {
                "Afghanistan": "AF"
           },
           {
                "Albania": "AL"
           },
           {
                "Algeria": "DZ"
           },
           {
                "American Samoa": "AS"      
           }
 }
```